# perl datetime output explain

Tags: perl, datetime

perl code:

```
#!/bin/env perl

use DateTime;

print DateTime->now;
```

OUTPUT:

```
2013-01-28T06:02:33
```

what's mean of 'T' letter in the output string ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ISO8601 and RFC3339 both use "T" to join the date and the time, and DateTime's default stringifier apparently adopted that convention. If you want another format, you can use one of the DateTime::Format::* modules or `->strftime`.

```
my $now = DateTime->now( time_zone => 'local' );
say $now->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');
```

Answer (score 3):

It stands for "Time".  You can read more at:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations

Answer (score 1):

It's the separator between date and time in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations). It's always a T in this format.

Answer (score 0):

> The character [T] shall be used as time designator to indicate the start of the representation of the time of day 
>   component in these expressions. The hyphen [-] and the colon [:] shall be used, in accordance with 4.4.4, as 
>   separators within the date and time of day expressions, respectively, when required.
>
> NOTE By mutual agreement of the partners in information interchange, the character [T] may be omitted in 
>   applications where there is no risk of confusing a date and time of day representation with others defined in this 
>   International Standard.

--[Data elements and interchange 
formats — Information interchange — 
Representation of dates and times, ISO 8601:2004(E)](http://dotat.at/tmp/ISO_8601-2004_E.pdf)